# How to auto populate multiple sheets from a single master tracker in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, auto-populate

I am having trouble creating a script that can populate multiple sheets from a single main tracker spreadsheet. More specifically, the Main tracker spreadsheet has a column named outcome in which a clients outcome is recorded. I want to be able to simply enter the outcome in the main tracker and have the entry of that value trigger the creation of a new row in a separate sheet that contains only information about that single outcome.

For example, in the master sheet I would entered " Added to waitlist" in the outcome column, which would thereby generate a copy of that record in another sheet with the same file called "Clients added to waitlist". I want to be able to do that for about 5 differentoutcomes.

Currently I have been using the following script for each of my 5 outcomes and 5 tabs to complete this task but I have yet to be successful:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Main Tracker" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() == "Added to Waitlist") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients Added to Waitlist");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  }
}
```

Whenever, I have more than one of the above script entries , only the very first one entered into the editor works, while the rest simply don't take. If some could help me reconcile this problem that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use more than one `onEdit` function in your script. Function names must be unique. You can have multiple conditional statements within the function, though.

```
if (event.value == "Added to Waitlist") {
    // do something 
} 
if (event.value == "Another thing") {
    // do something else
}
```

Or better yet, use [a switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

```
switch (event.value) {
  case "Added to Waitlist":
    // do something
    break
  case "Another thing":
    // do something else
    break
```

Note that `event.value` gives you the value entered on edit; you don't need to call `getValue` on the active cell to get it.

Similarly, `r = event.source.getActiveRange();` could be simply `r = event.range;`

Comment: I used the switch statement as you suggested and it works ! Thank you!